# Why is Spark 3 is asking me to specify the fully qualified class name everytime I use .parquet or .json or .csv?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Okay so i just migrated, from spark 2 to spark 3 and I changed dependencies. These dependencies are managed using SBT so when i submit my jobs to cluster i keep getting this error at places where .parquet is used for example

```
Multiple sources found for parquet (org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.parquet.ParquetDataSourceV2, org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat), INFO -  please specify the fully qualified class name
```

So I am not sure what is to be done, i have reinstalled the dependencies and updated the spark versions.
The quick fix like :

```
.format("org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat").save
```

works but i dont want to replace this everywhere.
I even mentioned the full class name in the configs while creating the spark sessions, but it still does not work, could someone suggest how do I fix this?

Comment: Please share your .sbt file, maybe it's because of dependencies conflict